# A tab.Panel inside a tab.Panel?

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I'm writing a simple app with a Home tab, in which there should be 3 tabs called "Breakfast", "Lunch" and Dinner. However the tabs don't work inside home. They display but are unresponsive to clicks.

Code:

view/Main.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
xtype: 'main',
config: {
    tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'menu',
        }
    ]
}
```

});

view/Menu.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.Menu', {
extend: 'Ext.tab.Panel',
requires: ['Ext.TitleBar'],
xtype: 'menu',
config: {
    title: 'Menu',
    iconCls: 'home',
    tabBar: {
        layout: {
            pack: 'center'
        }
    },
    items: [
        {
            title: 'Breakfast',
            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Breakfast Menu'
            },

            html: [
                "Breakfast menu will be here"
            ].join("")
        },
        {
            title: 'Lunch',


            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Lunch Menu'
            }

            html: [
                "Lunch menu will be here"
            ].join("")
        },
        {
            title: 'Dinner',

            items: {
                docked: 'top',
                xtype: 'titlebar',
                title: 'Dinner Menu'
            },

            html: [
                "Dinner menu will be here"
            ].join("")
        },
    ]
}
```

})

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed... Apparently naming xtype: 'menu' caused the problem. Don't name your xtype with generic names!